# email not sent with a dot in the host name default_url_options[:host]

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

This is a particularly weird problem...
I use Devise and I would like to receive emails when I ask to reset my password.

So I added this line to my development.rb file :

```
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

This is working great...

But if I change the address and write something with a dot in it, like my production address "xxx.herokuapp.com" no mail is sent. I get no errors, in the log I see a message telling the mail has been sent, but I receive nothing.

I only receive an email if there is no dot ('.') in the host name I provide.

---

Edit

If I use the default Devise:Mailer, everything works fine.
It must be a problem with my custom Mailer.

Here it is :
Mailer.rb

```
class Mailer < Devise::Mailer

  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  def headers_for(action, opts={})
    headers = {
        :subject       => t("devise.mailer.#{action}.subject"),
        :from          => mailer_sender(devise_mapping),
        :to            => resource.email,
        :bcc           => "myadresse",
        :template_path => template_paths
    }
  end

  def confirmation_instructions(record, opts={})
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record, opts={})
    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts)
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record, opts={})
    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions, opts)
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you modifying `development.rb` or `production.rb`?

Comment: Please have a look at my edit in the question. The problem appear as soon as there is a dot in the hostname, both in development and production environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-custom-mailer), you probably have to call `super` like this

```
def headers_for(action, opts={})
    headers = super.merge({
        :subject       => t("devise.mailer.#{action}.subject"),
        :from          => mailer_sender(devise_mapping),
        :to            => resource.email,
        :bcc           => "myadresse",
        :template_path => template_paths
    })
end
```